# AQXMLParser error: The current deployment target does not support automated __weak refrences

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I am trying to add AQXMLParser to my app, and among other issues that I am having with trying to set it up there are several errors relating to my question title.

```
The current deployment target does not support automated __weak refrences
```

I was wondering wether someone has experienced this problem before.

This is what lines they are on in the AQXMLParser.h file:

```
id __weak                               _delegate;
id<AQXMLParserProgressDelegate> __weak  _progressDelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id __weak delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AQXMLParserProgressDelegate> __weak progressDelegate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__weak won't work on iOS 4.x and earlier. It looks like AQXMLParser is either designed for GC (on Mac) or, more likely, ARC (on iOS5+).

Comment: okay, I read this else where also however I thought I was working with ios5 based code.. however now I am thinking that I am wrong.. time to check .

Comment: hm. Thinking about it, the way to do that in ARC would be @property (nonatomic, weak). This really looks more like GC code.

Comment: my code used to be 4.2 I have since changed my depoyment target to 5.0 and also my base sdk to 5.0... but still have the error what other things do i need to change to have my code 5.0

Comment: maybe I have picked up the wrong github directory.. because im pretty sure I have done everything thats needed to set it up but its still flipping me weird errors.. I have heard several people talking about aqxmlparser and heard of the benefits where I finally decided to go with it I find that the martial and discussion is pretty light.

Comment: ahh okay that fixed it updating my build in all of the right errors. however now I have another error which I will try to figure out.